# UITableView.visibleCells() is not returning all cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using a `UITableViewController`. The `UITableView` is presenting 11 custom Cells.
10 of those are dynamic, one is static.

Nevertheless counting the rows either with:

```
let cells = self.tableView.visibleCells as? [chatUebersicht]
```

or

```
for (var row = 0; row < gruppenNamen.count; row++) {      
  if let cell:chatUebersichtCell = table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)) as? chatUebersichtCell {            
    cells.append(cell)
  }
}
```

is returning the correct number. It is returning the number 5 each time.
I think there is an issue with preloading the cells. is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Do all 11 cells fit on the screen at the same time?  It seems likely that there are only 5 cells visible on the screen at a time.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why to you need ale the cells in the separate array?

Comment: There are only 5 cells visible at one time. I understand, that visibleCells does count these. But what is for the other array?    @Paulw11

Comment: @VojtaStavik I need some filtered cells in my UISearchBar.

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will also only return a cell if it is visible. Your second block of code effectively implements the same function as `visibleCells`. Since UITableViewCells are designed to be reused, any row  that is offscreen conceptually has no cell object assigned. You should operate on the underlying data rather than relying on cells. You typically only need to retrieve the cell if you want to update it in someway, which you don't need to do if a row is offscreen

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. Is there any other workaround? Since I am filtering for particular names, but also need to know which cell has which objectId, Image etc?

Comment: You shouldn't need to know which *cell*, but rather which *row*; this comes from examining your data array.  A cell is just a view of data, it doesn't represent any data itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`visibleCells` only returns the reusable cells you can currently see. That's the beauty of a `UITableView` - There isn't an instance of a cell for every row of data.

You should reevaluate what you are trying to do and determine whether it's a presentational operation or something that can be done by working with your array of data that feeds the tableview's data source.